# user not synchronized in 'my settings' once the UPN was changed in AD

Tags: sync, update, ad

we changed some upn in AD and the usernames did not updated and could not login. Once we restarted the server with sharepoint apps they could log in but if they go to username > My settings they still see the old user name. (Sharepoint 2010)

In this case of one user it will be

```
Move-SPUser -Identity "DOMAIN\jdoh" -NewAlias "DOMAIN\jdoe"
```

Will solve it only for one person. Is there a way how to update the usernames for everybody at once ?

Disclaimer: Apologize I'm not sharepoint expert.

Thank you !
Jim

Answer (score 0):

1st thing, I would recommend to run the FUll User Profile Sync followed by a Incremental Sync. After that Check the user's if it fix the problem.

Yes, Move-SpUser only move 1 users( one who is mentioned in the command). You have to run this command for all user one by one. Or write some kind of script which run for everybidy.
Check the below blog, he wrote a script to run for all users in web app.

http://blog.sharepoint-voodoo.net/?p=68

Comment: Hi, unfortunately there is no such thing as 'User Profile Service Application' in SharePoint Foundation